# http request to password protected files

Tags: android, .htaccess, http

The php files on my server are password protect with htaccess. How can I make request to these files through my android app?

I couldnt find any relevant answers with google search.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find your answer:

[Basic HTTP Authentication on Android](http://blog.leocad.io/post/basic-http-authentication-on-android)

Basically:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(YOUR_URL); // Or HttpPost(), depends on your needs
String credentials = YOUR_USERNAME + ":" + YOUR_PASSWORD;
String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.execute(request);
// You'll need to handle the exceptions thrown by execute()
```

You can replace the last line with:

EDITED:

You can try someting like this:

```
try {
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    //this is the login response, logged so you can see it - just use the second part of the log for anything you want to do with the data

    Log.d("Login: Response", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
} catch (IOException e) {
//if something went badly wrong
}
```

So you can view your response, maybe the problem is parsing the JSON.

Comment: I am getting unknown host exception.

Comment: my url is http://cdc.acjs.co/sync/upload_profiledata.php. Which was working perfectly fine before trying ur code. Am i missing anything?

Comment: sorry.. the unknown host exception was due to my internet connection. However, even with net connection, the request is nit successful as the json returned is null. Any ideas?

Comment: I am getting a null response

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PHP files are protected by **`HTTP Basic Authentication`**, you can request your php files using this special URL syntax:

```
http://validuser:validpassword@www.domain.com/validfile.php
```

Comment: When I request the url through browswer with your answer, I get a confirmation dialog. Would that hinder my app from accessing?

Comment: I am not a Android developer but knowing that it is all Java you can very well supply authentication info while opening a URL.

Comment: getting unknown host exception when request sent through app. However, it works perfectly when requested through browser

Comment: I have a feeling that it is happening due to the confirmation dialog. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that shouldn't cause `unknown host exception`